# int variable initialization failed in function

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a function wants to return a vector, inside of my function I setup an int counter (seasoning), which will increase by 1 after each loop. 
When I debug my function, I see my counter does not initialize, and correspondingly the first 29 calculations (seasoning < 30) I got 0 value.

Please see my code, thanks!

```
vector<float> 
RichardRollPrepayment::ComputingCPR(
  float maturity, 
  float settledTime, 
  float frequencyPreYear,
  float couponRate, 
  vector<float> mortgageRate
)  
{
  vector<float> cprVector(ceil((maturity-settledTime) * frequencyPreYear));
  float seasonality[] = {
    .94, .76, .73, .96, .98, .92, .99, 1.1, 1.18, 1.21, 1.23, .97
  };
  int seasoning = int(settledTime) * 12;

  for (int i = 0; i < cprVector.size(); i++) {

    if (seasoning < 30) {
      cprVector[i] = 
      (.2406 - .1389 * atan(5.952*(1.089 - couponRate/mortgageRate[i])))
        * (seasoning/30) * seasonality[seasoning%12];

      seasoning++;
    }

    else {
      cprVector[i] =
      (.2406 - .1389 * atan(5.952*(1.089 - couponRate/mortgageRate[i])))
        * 1 * seasonality[seasoning%12];

      seasoning++;
    }
  }

  return cprVector;
}
```

Comment: Is optimizations turned on?

Comment: What is the value of `settledTime`? Try removing `int` from the initializer expression: `int seasoning = settledTime * 12;`

Comment: @leppie what optimizations are your refer to?

Comment: @CiaPan you are right, this line is not so clear. When I test it I set settledTime as int. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `seasoning` is less than 30, you're multiplying with `seasoning/30`, which is 0 since `seasoning` is an integer.

Replace it with `seasoning / 30.0f`.